# Do online brokers offer access to Electronic Communication Network?

Tags: electronic-trading

I wonder which online broker offer access to Electronic Communication Network (ECN)? It does not look like individual can register with ECN.

Comment: You ask the question as if there is just 1 ECN.  There are many and all online brokers have access to them.  Whether you can route an order to a specific ECN personally is a different question.

Comment: @amdopt Thank you! I was actually interested in after hours trading and wonder if it is possible through online broker routing trades through particular ECN.